# Why does this simple Js function not return a value/object when () is added after the definition?

Tags: javascript, function

This function:

```
var f8 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } }
```

returns an object: `ƒ (param1 = "default") { alert(param1); }`

But this function:

```
var f9 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } }();
```

Does not, even after a function call `f9();`. Why?

It was my novice understanding that the appended parenthesis would simply call the outer function immediately after the function is defined. In other words be equivalent to:

```
var f10 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } };
f10();
```

and thereby return the same function object as before. On a side note, I'd love it if someone would explain when one should use `var f11 = (function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } }());` over `var f11 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } }();` I've seen both, ones with the outer parens, and ones without, seemingly in the same context.

Comment: Yes, you are calling the outer function, so you get the inner function when you do `f9`, if you call `f9` however you are calling the inner function

Comment: You're returning a function that is called, and then doesn't return anything, which means it returns `undefined`, as expected. The first example returns a reference to a function.

Comment: It sounds like you guys are saying that the `f9` object is 'constantly called', as in the appended `()` is part of the definition itself and is not equivalent to the `f10` example. Anyone up for making a more formal answer for clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns the inner function, in order to call the alert call the inner function that is now f9

```js
var f9 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } }();

console.log(f9);
f9();
```

this would be equivalent to

```js
var f10 = function() { return function(param1 = "default") { alert(param1); } };
console.log(f10);
var f9 = f10();
console.log(f9);
f9();
```